# How to add 0 before in the month field using transformer in datastage

Tags: datastage

I would like to add 0 for month field

For example from source I receiving 1 and I would like to add 0 before 1

Example:
Source - 1
Target - 01

Field Data type - Integer

Comment: Use string concatenationfor it - like "0" : number

Answer (score 0):

To format an integer month into a 2-digit string *without having the rest of the date (so you cannot use date conversion function on-the-fly)*, you can trick the derivation by adding 100 to the number and then treat it as string by only passing the two most-right characters to the output:

`Right(DSLink2.Month + 100,2)`

This way, you make sure to only add a zero in front of one-digit months.

*Beginners Hint: Since you mentioned the datatype is integer, please note that of course the output cannot stay integer which would drop leading zeroes again. Output datatype must be a string type, e.g. Char(2).*